# Is it possible to use count to get total rows while maintaining query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query gets all the results from a table called video

```
SELECT video.* from video 
LEFT JOIN conv_progress on video.vid_id=conv_progress.vid_id 
LEFT JOIN upload_progress on video.vid_id=upload_progress.vid_id 
where conv_progress.vid_id is null
AND upload_progress.vid_id is null
ORDER BY video.timestamp DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

I just want to count the total results for pagination usage. The current `limit ?,?` reduces my count if I use rowCount().

```
SELECT video.*, COUNT(vid_id) as count from video 
LEFT JOIN conv_progress on video.vid_id=conv_progress.vid_id 
LEFT JOIN upload_progress on video.vid_id=upload_progress.vid_id 
where conv_progress.vid_id is null
AND upload_progress.vid_id is null
ORDER BY video.timestamp DESC LIMIT ?, ?',$variables
```

This query only returns one result but a proper count number. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL has a `sql_calc_found_rows` extensions, which forces the DB engine to calculate how many rows WOULD have been retrieve if it wasn't for the limit statement. You can then retrieve this full-row-count with [`SELECT found_rows()][1]` in a separate query.

Basic syntax for the parent query would be:

```
SELECT sql_calc_found_rows video.*  FROM video
...
LIMIT ?,?
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply calculate the total:

```
SELECT count(*) from video 
LEFT JOIN conv_progress on video.vid_id=conv_progress.vid_id 
LEFT JOIN upload_progress on video.vid_id=upload_progress.vid_id 
where conv_progress.vid_id is null
AND upload_progress.vid_id is null
```

Then, from the language you're using, determine the smallest of between the returned count and the number of rows your query would have limited with your two ? parameters. In PHP:

```
min($query_count,$upper_bound-$lower_bound)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but the problem is I need the limit for pagination. With my entire query intact, your solution returns nothing.

Comment: It sould always return one integer. You'd have to query the database twice, once to get your columns from video, the other to get the count.